# How can I get rid of error mentioned below and configure composer for first Laravel project using homestead

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have made a fresh installation of composer in Windows 8.1 using Installer.

-> After that i have create a composer.json file(shown below downloaded from github) in C:\Users\MyPC

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
 }
}
```

-> After that I have run the command "composer update" which downloaded a lot of 
   stuff but I don't know where.

->After that I am trying to run 'composer global require “laravel/installer”
' command which gives me error shown below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUvaY.png

I don't know what to do next as I am new to this stuff. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already created the composer.json inside C:\Users\MyPC , you should try running `composer install` from the same path so it will install the necessary files according to the settings in composer.json. It should have the new files and folders inside the C:\Users\MyPC (Since you mentioned `composer update` already downloaded stuff, then the updated files and folders should already by there. You should also be seeing a composer.lock too.)

I suggest though you move the composer.json to another folder to better represent your laravel project because if I'm not mistaken, MyPC refers to home directory of logged in user 'MyPC'.

There should be no need to use 'composer global require "laravel/installer"' since for that, you will need to run something like `laravel new <proj_name>`  in order to create project folder for you with all the necessary dependencies.

Which is about the equivalent of doing `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <proj_name>`.

Comment: Yes you are right, there is a file "composer.lock" in my home directory i.e. c:\users\MyPC. In which folder composer download its components, is it called "vendor" folder.

Comment: Is there any problem in keeping composer.json file in home directory. b/c everything related to laravel is in my home directory i.e. homestead, vagrant files, vb and all.

Comment: 1 more thing ,Please review the composer.json file code above and tell me if anyhting is extra in it b/c I recieved a error massage related to database when I updated the composer last time.

Comment: After running the "composer install" command, I get this error massage...    

Loading composer repositories with package information... 
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file... 
Nothing to install or update... 
Generating optimized autoload files... 

  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "database/seeds" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder... 

What should I do..

Answer (score 1):

I havent used laravel/installer yet, but just 5 minutes ago I installed a fresh laravel 5.5

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel NAME_OF_PROJECT
```

You have to run this in the terminal, in the folder in which you want to create the project. It will create a folder "NAME_OF_PROJECT" in which Laravel will be installed.

The `composer update` should work as well I believe, just make sure you run the command while you are in the same folder as the file itself. Composer should than install the files in that folder. The composer.json file you are using is the default for Laravel 5.5